# Windows chess program that can load PGN files per command line

Tags: windows

the program should display a PGN file, be fast to run, and absolutely be expected to be callable by the command line (passing the PGN file as an argument).
The reason is I began to create a concept map about an opening, and I can call from this map some EXE programs. I would like to display some games as examples of the nodes.

I already searched, but till now I found nothing.

Comment: SCID and Arena?

Comment: @fuxia that's the answer I'd give, would you mind posting it as an answer instead of a comment please?

Comment: @SmallChess Can't you call SCID by command line anymore? Maybe not by default, but I used to have mine set up so that I could access them by command line: I called my engine through SCID to analyze positions and return a .pgn with comments where the evaluation changed more than some number. The truth is that you're just calling SCID, opening it in the background, doing stuff and then closing it, but in practice you only use the command line.

Comment: @PabloS.Ocal Done. :) I wasn't sure whether the OP didn't find those programs or ruled them out for some reasons.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are at least two Windows programs that you can start per command line: [Arena](http://www.playwitharena.com/) and [SCID](http://scid.sourceforge.net/) (or [SCID vs PC](http://scidvspc.sourceforge.net/)).

#### Arena

To open a PGN file in Arena, call it with:

```
Arena.exe -loadgamefile "path/to/sample.pgn"
```

There are many more options listed in the help file under *Miscellaneous/Command Line Parameters*. `analyze` is particular useful.

#### SCID and SCIDvsPC

Both come with the same very small set of command line options. Again see the help file.

Open a PGN file with:

```
scid.exe "path/to/sample.pgn"
```

Arena's command line support is far superior in my opinion.